Buttons not clickable after installing the app running on iOS 18.2
Does anyone have a problem with buttons not clickable in the lists of elements? If I have a list of 30 elements, some of them are clickable and some not. The button is a basic button that prints something in the console. After refresh, click ability is changed but still some clickable and some not.
I noticed some similar issues with onTapGesture on StackOverflow but my problem is a button. However, I have the same problem with onTapGesture (where I use it) in some of my View components and changing it with highPriorityGesture will not solve the problem since I can't click on the child elements of those Views anymore...
My colleague with the same code (same branch) releases the app via TestFlight and it works just fine even for iOS 18.2. He has Xcode 15.4. I'm using Xcode 16.2.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?
EDIT:
Buttons were part of the Views and eventually views were part of the TabView. After removing TabView buttons are clickable again. Is there any configuration that I need to set for TabView?
The selection of the TabView is Int, Hashable enum.

If your colleague is using Xcode 15, then it’s likely the code is being compiled with Swift 5. There is an issue with buttons in lists when using Swift 6 - this is likely a bug on Apple’s side.

I thought so too but in Build Settings I can see that my Swift Compiler - Language is still set to Swift 5.
